# Speedup search of Elements

Tags: r, search

I got two data.frames `m` (23 columns 135.973 rows) with the two important columns

```
head(m[,2])
# [1] "chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1"
head(m[,7])
# [1] 3661216 3661217 3661223 3661224 3661564 3661567
```

and `search` (4 columns 1.019.423 rows) with three important columns

```
head(search[,1])
# [1] "chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1"
head(search[,3])
# [1] 3000009 3003160 3003187 3007262 3028947 3050944
head(search[,4])
# [1] 3000031 3003182 3003209 3007287 3028970 3050995
```

For each row in m I like to get the information if the `m`[XX,7] position is between any  position of `search`[,3] and `search`[,4]. So `search`[,3] can be considered as "start" and `search`[,4] as "end". In addition `search`[,1] and `m`[,2] have to be identical.

Example:

`m` at row 215
"chr1"   10.984.038
hits in `search` at line 2898
"chr1" 10.984.024     10.984.046

In general I'm not interested which line or how many lines of `search` could be found. I just want the information for any line of `m` is there a matching line in `search` yes or no.

I'm ending up in this function:

```
f_4<-function(x,y,z){
    for (out in 1:length(x[,1])) {
        z[out]<-length(which((y[,1]==x[out,2]) &(x[out,7]>=y[,3]) &(x[out,7]<=y[,4])))
    }
    return(z)
}

found4<-vector(length=length(m[,1]), mode="numeric")
found4<-f_4(m,search,found4)
```

It took 3 hours to run this code.
I have already tried some speedup approaches, however I didn't manage to get any of this running proper or faster.

I even tried some `lappy`/`apply` approaches -which worked but aren't faster-. However they failed when trying to speed up using `parLapply`/`parRapply`.

Anybody got a quite faster approach and may can give some advise?

EDIT 2015/09/18
Found another way to speed up, using `foreach` `%dopar%`.

```
    f5<-function(x,y,z){
          foreach(out=1:length(x[,1]), .combine="c") %dopar%  {
            takt<-1000
            z=length(which((y[,1]==x[out,2]) &(x[out,7]>=y[,3]) &(x[out,7]<=y[,4]) ))
          }   
          return(z)
        }

found5<-vector(length=length(m[,1]), mode="numeric")
found5<-f5(m,search,found5)
```

Only need 45min. However I'm always getting 0 only. Thing I need to read some more of the `foreach` `%dopar%` tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try merging with subsequent logical subsetting. First let's create some mock data:

```
set.seed(123) # used for reproducibility
m <-as.data.frame(matrix(sample(50,7000, replace=T), ncol=7, nrow=1000))
search <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(50,1200, replace=T), ncol=4, nrow=300))
```

Since we want to compare different rows of the two sets, we can use the criterion that `m[,2]` should be equal to `search[,1]`. For convenience we can name these columns "ID" in both sets:

```
m <- cbind(m,seq_along(1:nrow(m)))
search <- cbind(search,seq_along(1:nrow(search)))
colnames(m) <- c("a","ID","c","d","e","f","val","rownum.m")
colnames(search) <- c("ID","nothing","start","end", "rownum.s")
```

We have added a column to `m` named 'rownum.m' and a similar column to `search` which in the end will help identifying the resulting entries in the initial dataset.

Now we can merge the data sets, such that the ID is the same:

```
m2 <- merge(m,search)
```

In a final step, we can perform a logical subset of the merged data set and assign the output to a new data frame `m3`:

```
m3 <- m2[(m2[,"val"] >= m2[,"start"]) & (m2[,"val"] <= m2[,"end"]),]
#> head(m3)
#   ID  a  c  d  e  f val rownum.m nothing start end rownum.s
#5   1 14 36 36 31 30  25      846      10    20  36      291
#13  1 34 49 24  8 44  21      526      10    20  36      291
#17  1 19 32 29 44 24  35      522       6    33  48      265
#20  1 19 32 29 44 24  35      522      32    31  50       51
#21  1 19 32 29 44 24  35      522      10    20  36      291
#29  1  6 50 10 13 43  22       15      10    20  36      291
```

If we are only interested in a `TRUE/FALSE` statement whether a specific row of `m` matches the criterions, we can define a vector `match_s`:

```
match_s <- m$rownum.m %in% m3$rownum.m
```

which can be stored as an additional column in the original data set `m`:

```
m <- cbind(m,match_s)
```

Finally, we can remove the auxiliary column 'rownum.m' from the data set `m` which is no longer needed, with `m <- m[,-8]`.

The result is:

```
> head(m)
#   a ID  c  d  e  f val match_s
#1 15 14  8 11 16 13  23   FALSE
#2 40 30  8 48 42 50  20   FALSE
#3 21  9  8 19 30 36  19    TRUE
#4 45 43 26 32 41 33  27   FALSE
#5 48 43 25 10 15 13   4   FALSE
#6  3 24 31 33  8  5  36   FALSE
```

Comment: `m` and `search` don't have same length, subsetting will not work

Comment: This one works fine for small `m` and `search`.  Dealing with high number of rows (135k and 1.019k) the merge will run out of memory..sadly.

Comment: Maybe you could use subsets of the original data sets for this part of the analysis, retaining only the necessary columns (start, end, val, ID, rownum.m, rownum.s) and merge these subsets. Keeping 23 columns seems necessary if all you want is the vector `match_s`.

Comment: Already tried. Also tried to subset the ID list `merge(grep("1",m[,"ID"]),grep("1",search[,"ID"]))` still to large (this one needs about 45GB of RAM

Comment: Ouch. Then the only thing I can think of is to split `search` into chunks of a few tens of thousand of rows each, and to check whether you obtain a match of the set `m` in any of these chunks (using a loop).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find SNPs (say) inside a set of genomic regions, don't use R. Use [BEDOPS](http://bedops.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Convert your SNP or single-base positions to a three-column BED file. In R, make a three-column data table with `m[,2]`, `m[,7]` and `m[,7] + 1`, which represent the chromosome, start and stop position of the SNP. Use `write.table()` to write out this data table to a tab-delimited text file.

Do the same with your genomic regions: Write `search[,1]`, `search[,3]`, and `search[,4]` to a three-column data table representing the chromosome, start and stop position of the region. Use `write.table()` to write this out to a tab-delimited text file.

Use [`sort-bed` to sort both BED files](http://bedops.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/reference/file-management/sorting/sort-bed.html). This step might be optional, but it doesn't take long to do and it guarantees that the files are prepped for use with BEDOPS tools.

Finally, [use `bedmap` on the two BED files to map SNPs to genomic regions](http://bedops.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/usage-examples/snps-within-dhses.html). Mapping associates SNPs with regions. The `bedmap` tool can report which SNPs map to a region, or report the number of SNPs, or one or more of many other operations. The [documentation](http://bedops.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/reference/statistics/bedmap.html) for `bedmap` goes into more detail on the list of operations, but the [provided example](http://bedops.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/usage-examples/snps-within-dhses.html) should get you started quickly.

If your data are in BED format, or can be quickly coerced into BED format, don't use R for genomic operations, as it is slow and memory-intensive. The BEDOPS toolkit introduced the use of sorting to make genomic operations fast, with low memory overhead.

Comment: Well they aren't SNPs but could be interpreted in the same direction. Tested your solution, works fine...However in the end I can't use it on the productive machine. No external programms allowed. Only R and R packages.

Comment: R is not a very good tool for this kind of problem, but I hope you find a better solution.